# Subdivision Surface seam artifact?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, artifacts

so, I'm kinda new to 3d modelling (I've done some simpler low poly people and objects in the past) and I keep running into this issue with the Subdivision Surface modifier where it leaves this seam like mark on the mesh.
[image]

I tried looking at just the wireframe it looks like some vertices just bend in(?).

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what this is and the mesh doesn't look like it has any extruding leftovers.

Comment: hello, maybe there are some overlapping vertices? could you share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sure, here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/ecb6cd4c865745dcba5d79eaebf6c93f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see some faces are flipped, you need to recalculate the normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*):

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, that was totally it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user128400 Anothe thing: apart from moonboots' solution, before I checked the face orientation I was wondering why it's not looking smooth although I chose smooth shading in _Object Mode_. What most people don't know, you can set smooth or flat shading even in _Edit Mode_ for selected faces - if you set them to flat, they won't be smoothed in _Object Mode_ sometimes. So if you are still experiencing this, best would be to hit A to select all faces in _Face Select_ mode, right click and _Shade Smooth_.