# i blocked out the character according to parts. Then I joined the torso and legs, shaded it smooth, and added a subdivision mod. what's this crease?

Tags: normals, subdivision-surface

**I want to get rid of it but its frustrating me :<**
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have inverted normals? In Edit mode, select all and press Shift N. If it doesn't work you may have inner faces or overlapping vertices...

Comment: @moonboots It's fixed now, I inverted the normals :> thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subdivision Surface seam artifact?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231650/subdivision-surface-seam-artifact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted normals, in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.